# Monte Carlo Simulations: Probability that 5 consecutive rolls of seven will occur

Tags: simulation, probability, modeling, montecarlo

I just need your help about Monte Carlo Simulations. Here's the problem.

> On a roll of two dice, a total of seven occurs with probability 1/6.
>   In 100 rolls of the dice, what is the probability that five
>   consecutive rolls of seven will occur?

*(This is an exercise from Mathematical Modeling and Simulations by M. Meerschaert)*

I made a pseudo-code using R:

```
dice.sims1 = function(trials){
occur
for (j in 1:trials){
x = 0
y = 0
n = 0
result = NULL
while (n<100){
n = n+1
result[n] = sample(1:6,1) + sample(1:6,1)
if(result[n] == 7){
x = x+1
}else {x = 0}
if(x>=5){
y = y+1
}
}
occur[j] = y 
}
print(mean(occur)/100)
}
```

Is this correct? If so, how do I interpret my result?
If it's not correct, can you help me correct it?

Thanks and have a good day.

Comment: Really? And what on the second line `occur` is doing? Unless it is declared in the code you didn't show us, it will produce an error `Error in dice.sims1(10000) : object 'occur' not found`

Comment: Anyway, modulo ill-defined problem (how exactly `5 in a row` defined?), with some modification it looks ok, please check the answer

Comment: I forgot to set occur = NULL, sir. Sorry. but in my edited code, I made it possible to run.

Comment: Please don't call me sir, this makes me nervous...

Comment: I am very sorry about my previous code, sir. Regardless, I was able to run it after setting occur = NULL. With regard to 5 in a row, I explained my argument below as to why I count 6 consecutive rolls of 7 as two. It's not also clear to me if we should count it as one or two but that's how I will defend my answer. Thank you very much, sir.

Comment: I don't mean to make you feel like that. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from bugs in the code, there is an unclear condition - if you have 6 rolls of 7 in a row, is it counted as one or as two?

You count it as two here

```
if(x>=5){
    y = y+1
}
```

Then 7 rolls in a row would make it three etc.

UPDATE

```
dice.sims1 = function(trials) {
    occur = rep(0, times=trials)
    for (j in 1:trials) {
        x = 0
        y = 0
        n = 0
        while (n<100) {
            n = n + 1
            result = sample(1:6,1) + sample(1:6,1)
            if(result == 7){
                x = x+1
            } else {
                x = 0
            }
            if(x>=5) {
                y = y+1
                x = 0 # !!! unclear problem setup
            }
        }
        occur[j] = y
    }
    mean(occur)
}

set.seed(12345)

print(dice.sims1(10000))
```

will produce 0.0109 with marked line and 0.0131 with marked line removed

UPDATE II

Version without an array, direct summation

```
dice.sims <- function(trials) {
    s <- 0L
    for (i in 1:trials) {

        ncons <- 0L
        for(k in 1:100) {
            roll <- sample.int(6,1) + sample.int(6,1)
            if (roll == 7L) {
                ncons <- ncons + 1L # good roll
            } else {
                ncons <- 0L # bad one, back to square one
            }
            if (ncons >= 5L) {
                s <- s + 1L
                # ncons <- 0L # start from the beginning
            }
        }
    }
    as.numeric(s)/as.numeric(trials)
}
```

Comment: _if you have 6 rolls of 7 in a row, is it counted as one or as two?_
well, i counted it as two sir. I was thinking that if i considered the second 7 as the first, third 7 as the second, ..., and sixth 7 as the fifth, then I can observe another 5 consecutive rolls of 7 in a row.

Sir, what does the set.seed(12345) does on the code? And I suppose your answer is in percent? We differ in our answer because I divided mine with 100 (to get the probability of having a 5 consecutive rolls of 7 in 100 rolls)

Comment: @raffycee `set.seed(12345)` is setting the seed value of the random number generator and, thus, making the result reproducible.

Comment: @raffycee ok, so in my code line marked with exclamations to be removed. My result is in probability, but normalized per trial/run of 100 rolls, not per 1 roll as you're impl\ying. What did you get?

Comment: I understand. Mine is around 0.000124 at dice.sims1(1000000). Maybe because I divided it with 100?

Comment: @raffycee yes, pretty close I think, with difference in 1/100 division. Could you call set.seed(12345) in your code and see what you get?

Comment: the result is 0.000127 at dice.sims1(100000). you can check the how i run it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B48EN8ddCsLZMWVJSWdKLXJpa28/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @raffycee same here (well, times 100)

Comment: I am just wondering which approach is correct. Dividing it with 100 or not?

Comment: @raffycee Either way would work as soon as you clearly describe what you observed. Just for fun, I've added version of the code I wrote myself, with direct summation, enjoy!

Comment: @raffycee Just one thing to note - your version is using numerics. When dealing with numerics sometimes you might miss the condition due to not-quit-the-same numbers, loss of precision etc. Thus, for discrete problems like dice rolling I always try to work with integers, as one can see in the second code example